# Alterantive to jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional in xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

what is the alterantive to jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional option  in xmlhttprequest?
or
how to serialize the query params for a xmlhttprequest?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize object, you can use `$.param()`. On the contrary, if you want to disable it globally, you can set `$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`

Comment: i am not using $.ajax() for the requests, i am  using XMLHttpRequest().I want the alternative for $.ajaxSettings.traditional option in XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to change it globally, do the following:

`$.param({...}, true)`